# Does fragment shader process all pixels from vertex shader?

Tags: c++, opengl

If I have only the vertex shader and fragment shader in my pipeline, what I would like to know is does the fragment shader receive each individual processed vertex from the vertex shader or does it wait until all of the values that are passed in to the vertex shader are processed before giving them to the fragment shader to then individually process each pixel or process them all at once?

Also does the fragment shader get immediately executed after each vertex shader execution before the vertex shader gets the next vertices or vertex input to process?

Meaning if I have my fragment shader doing this:

```
const GLchar * vertex_shader_source = {
    "#version 430 core\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vert;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vert;\n"
    "}\n"
};
const GLchar * fragment_shader_source = {
    "#version 430 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(gl_VertexID/100,gl_VertexID/100,gl_VertexID/100,1.0f);\n"
    "}\n"
};
```

Would the fragment shader actually be in sync with each vertex index being processed from the buffer?

Comment: Why does it matter (not being a jerk, just a straightforward question)? GPUs tend to do a lot in parallel and I don't think you can reliably predict what you want to know since it would probably vary based on the specific gpu and driver and so on. GPUs that do tiled rendering for example render your scene in tiles, so they might not process all the vertices in your geometry with the vertex shader at once before rasterizing with the fragment shader.

Comment: Yes, maybe, or no, depending on which GPU. Most GPU's will have stuff to avoid working on vertices that don't contribute to the final image, and the shader obviously won't see such "culled" vertices. And whether it's immediately after of a long time after is again dependent on the GPU design. It could be that it processes ALL vertices, and runs the fragment shader when that is done, or it could be that it does them a few at a time, or truly pipelined. Most likely, in any realistic system, they are not "in sync" - the GPU will perform better asynchronously.

Comment: ... `gl_VertexID` is only available in the vertex shader, not in the fragment shader!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is misleading. It's not the case that fragment shaders receive vertices. They receive fragments. Between vertex and fragment shaders, there's a lot of hardware that takes multiple vertices, form triangles out of them, do a bunch of processing on them (culling, clipping...) and then rasterize them (transform triangles to a bunch of covered squares) to generate the fragments that will get executed on the fragment shader.

All that to say that there isn't a natural mapping from vertex ids to fragments (and indeed you need multiple vertices to generate a fragment, and in many cases, a single vertex will contribute to multiple triangles too).

So there is simply no way to meaningfully use a gl_VertexID inside a fragment shader.

Now, with respect to "do vertex shaders run all before fragments" or such questions... Any fragment that was generated necessarily had the vertex positions already computed (since it's required to compute the fragment coverage). But it's about the only guarantee you'll get.

Tile-base deferred renderers, e.g. will typically process all the vertices first if it can (on the whole frame!), and only later *a frame later* will it process all the fragments. In contrast, "Immediate Mode Renderers" will tend to process triangles as they become available. There's isn't a lot of ways to really observe those things, and I don't know that many people did do the observation on the few methods available.